# How to make search filter and dropdown filter work together Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a gallery with search filter and drop down filter. The problem I have is that when I use the search it disregards the dropdowns and vice versa.

I want to be able to filter the gallery by typing in the search a age-15, then further filtering by level-beginner and gender-female and teacher name - liz.

So the result should show students who are female, age 15, a beginner, and student of liz.

The dropdowns work seamlessly together meaning I can get it to filter by level, gender, and teacher. But if I want to use the search bar it resets and only searching by whatever I input, in this example being the age.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container-fluid dashboard">
      <!--TITLE -->
      <div class="title container row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h1 class="heading">Your Dancers</h1> 
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row container" style="margin: auto;">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
              <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Search by name, age, level, etc..">
          </div>




        <div class="col-sm-2"></div>

          <div class="col-sm-2 " style="text-align: right;">
              <select class="level">
                 <option value="all">All Levels</option>
                  <option value="Pre-Beginner"> Pre-Beginner (1)</option>
                  <option value="Beginner"> Beginner (1)</option>
                  <option value="Novice"> Novice (3)</option>
                  <option value="Prize Winner"> Prize Winner (3)</option>
                  <option value="Prelim Champion"> Prelim Champion (1)</option>
                  <option value="Open Champion"> Open Champion (3)</option>
              </select>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-2 " style="text-align: right;">
              <select class="gender">
                  <option value="all">All Genders</option>
                  <option value="Female"> Female</option>
                  <option value="Male"> Male</option>
              </select>
          </div>



          <div class="col-sm-2 " style="text-align: right;">
              <select class="teachers">
                  <option value="all">All Teachers</option>

                  <option value="Mike" > Mike</option>

                  <option value="Mr. Alpha" > Mr. Alpha</option>

                  <option value="Ms. Lee" > Ms. Lee</option>

                  <option value="Liz" > Liz</option>
                                    </select>
          </div>

      </div>


      <!--DANCER GALLERY-->
      <div class="row container FilterContainer" style="margin: auto; margin-bottom: 2rem;">


          <div class="col-sm-3 column" data-level="Novice" data-teacher="Liz" data-gender="Female">
              <a href="dancerProfile?id=1" class="link">
                  <div class="content">
                      <img src="uploads/profile-icon.png" alt="Lace" style="width:80%; height: 170px;">
                      <h4>Lace - Novice</h4>
                      <p>Age: 14, teacher: Liz</p>
                  </div>
              </a>
          </div>


          <div class="col-sm-3 column" data-level="Novice" data-teacher="Mr. Alpha" data-gender="Female">
              <a href="dancerProfile?id=3" class="link">
                  <div class="content">
                      <img src="uploads/1782517_575923289159969_1857743309_o.jpg" alt="Rhea" style="width:80%; height: 170px;">
                      <h4>Rhea - Novice</h4>
                      <p>Age: 5, teacher: Mr. Alpha</p>
                  </div>
              </a>
          </div>


          <div class="col-sm-3 column" data-level="Open Champion" data-teacher="Ms. Lee" data-gender="Female">
              <a href="dancerProfile?id=48" class="link">
                  <div class="content">
                      <img src="imgs/profile-icon%20(1).png" alt="Isabelle" style="width:80%; height: 170px;">
                      <h4>Isabelle - Open Champion</h4>
                      <p>Age: 15, teacher: Ms. Lee</p>
                  </div>
              </a>
          </div>


      </div>
  </div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
  //SEARCH FILTER

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $(".column").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
  });
});


//call the same function for each select's change event
$("select.level, select.gender, select.teachers").change(updateStudents);

function updateStudents() {
//get all the values
  var level = $('select.level').val();
  var gender = $('select.gender').val();
  var teachers = $('select.teachers').val();

  $('.FilterContainer')
  .find('.column')
  .hide()
  .filter(function () {
    var okLevel = true;
    if(level !== "all"){
      var okLevel = $(this).attr('data-level') === level;
    }


    var okGender = true;
    if(gender !== "all"){
      okGender = $(this).attr('data-gender') === gender;
    }

    var okTeachers = true;
    if(teachers !== "all"){
      okTeachers = $(this).attr('data-teacher') === teachers;
    }

   //only fade a room if it satisfies all three conditions
    return okLevel && okGender && okTeachers;
  }).fadeIn('fast');
}
});
```

Comment: You should move your `<input>` filter into `updateStudents`. Then each independent column will need to be search independently. The reason is because your filters are all working independently on the whole of the data set. it is only `updateStudents()` that aggregates the filters for the columns. Since you don't aggregate the text filter, the entire data set is displayed based upon the unaggregated filter.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I thought this made a lot of sense. But when I moved the input into updateStudents the input stopped working altogether.

Comment: Post a working example : [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - No PHP. Just the raw HTML output and this JavaScript. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just updated the post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I meant by placing the text search inside the `updateStudents()` function. As you can see, it is written exactly like the other filters, with only the filter logic being different.

You were so very close. Hope this helps.

```js
$("select.level, select.gender, select.teachers").change(updateStudents);
$("#myInput").on("keyup", updateStudents);

function updateStudents() {
  var level = $('select.level').val();
  var gender = $('select.gender').val();
  var teachers = $('select.teachers').val();
  var search = $("#myInput").val();

  $('.FilterContainer')
    .find('.column')
    .hide()
    .filter(function() {
      var okLevel = true;
      var okGender = true;
      var okTeachers = true;
      var okSearch = true;

      if (level !== "all") {
        okLevel = $(this).attr('data-level') === level;
      }
      if (gender !== "all") {
        okGender = $(this).attr('data-gender') === gender;
      }
      if (teachers !== "all") {
        okTeachers = $(this).attr('data-teacher') === teachers;
      }
      if (search !== '') {
        okSearch = $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1;
      }
      //only fade a room if it satisfies all four conditions
      return okLevel && okGender && okTeachers && okSearch;
    }).fadeIn('fast');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="4.1.3" rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="4.1.3" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script defer src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid dashboard">
    <!--TITLE -->
    <div class="title container row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h1 class="heading">Your Dancers</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row container" style="margin: auto;">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Search by name, age, level, etc.." />
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 " style="text-align: right;">
        <select class="level">
          <option value="all">All Levels</option>
          <option value="Pre-Beginner"> Pre-Beginner (1)</option>
          <option value="Beginner"> Beginner (1)</option>
          <option value="Novice"> Novice (3)</option>
          <option value="Prize Winner"> Prize Winner (3)</option>
          <option value="Prelim Champion"> Prelim Champion (1)</option>
          <option value="Open Champion"> Open Champion (3)</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 " style="text-align: right;">
        <select class="gender">
          <option value="all">All Genders</option>
          <option value="Female"> Female</option>
          <option value="Male"> Male</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 " style="text-align: right;">
        <select class="teachers">
          <option value="all">All Teachers</option>
          <option value="Mike"> Mike</option>
          <option value="Mr. Alpha"> Mr. Alpha</option>
          <option value="Ms. Lee"> Ms. Lee</option>
          <option value="Liz"> Liz</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--DANCER GALLERY-->
    <div class="row container FilterContainer" style="margin: auto; margin-bottom: 2rem;">
      <div class="col-sm-3 column" data-level="Novice" data-teacher="Liz" data-gender="Female">
        <a href="dancerProfile?id=1" class="link">
          <div class="content">
            <img src="uploads/profile-icon.png" alt="Lace" style="width:80%; height: 170px;" />
            <h4>Lace - Novice</h4>
            <p>Age: 14, teacher: Liz</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 column" data-level="Novice" data-teacher="Mr. Alpha" data-gender="Female">
        <a href="dancerProfile?id=3" class="link">
          <div class="content">
            <img src="uploads/1782517_575923289159969_1857743309_o.jpg" alt="Rhea" style="width:80%; height: 170px;" />
            <h4>Rhea - Novice</h4>
            <p>Age: 5, teacher: Mr. Alpha</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 column" data-level="Open Champion" data-teacher="Ms. Lee" data-gender="Female">
        <a href="dancerProfile?id=48" class="link">
          <div class="content">
            <img src="imgs/profile-icon%20(1).png" alt="Isabelle" style="width:80%; height: 170px;" />
            <h4>Isabelle - Open Champion</h4>
            <p>Age: 15, teacher: Ms. Lee</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```